# Openldap error: alock package is unstable

Tags: linux, centos, ldap

I am configuring openldap on a CentOS 5.3 machine. When I start the ldap service I get the following exception:

> Checking configuration files for
>   slapd:  bdb_db_open: alock package is
>   unstable backend_startup_one:
>   bi_db_open failed! (-1) slap_startup
>   failed (test would succeed using the
>   -u switch) [FAILED]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is often due to incorrect permissions on the actual db files, I don't know where openldap on Centos keep them (though I'd guess /var/lib/ldap or so), verify that the user slapd will run with has access.

If that isn't the issue, I'd try running with strace what (if any) error occurs.

Another approach is to use db_verify/db_recover to verify and salvage the db if necessary.